# Url rewriter is messing up my form posts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I need some ideas i am using url rewriter for seo purposes.. maybe I shouldnt be doing this i am not sure if you have any comments on this let me know

I am making sure that all requests get directed to www.mydomai.com for
www.mydomian.com/home and www.mydomain.com/home/index as there all the same page but with mvc obviously you could get to them by all of these urls.. I am thinking this could cause duplicate content issues with seo so i wrote some rules
              
                
                
              
              
                
                
              
This works fine any request to any of these urls redirects to www.mydomin.com

the problem that i have is that i have a partial form post that updates to the home controller It will not post back as in the net panel it says url permenatly moved I am guessing this is to do with my url rewriting. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem I have fixed it... I am using the url writer to make urls friendly ie making them all lowercase to avoid duplicates and taking the trailing slash off to ensure that I have no links that are slightly different going to the same place.. Forms do not like this if you call them with capital letters in the names.. It initiates the form via ajax but when you go to update it says 301 removed in the net tab for updatepost. You need to ensure you call them with lower case controller and action..